# How to update core-js to core-js@3 dependency

Tags: package-management, dependencies, npm

While I was trying to install and setup react native, the **precaution** observed about the core-js version as `update your core-js@... to core-js@3`
But don't know how to update my core-js.

One things is very obvious that its the dependency in the **NPM** package as:

Following output is getting by **`npm list -g`**:

```
├─┬ create-react-native-app@2.0.2   // <= Please update me : )
│ ├─┬ babel-runtime@6.26.0
│ │ ├── core-js@2.6.5
│ │ └── regenerator-runtime@0.11.1
```

Now I don't know how to update it, currently I am looking this to solve my issue [Create React Native App](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app)

Thanks to [Syed Shamikh Shabbir](https://www.facebook.com/shami.syed) who gave me this [link](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/docs/2019-03-19-core-js-3-babel-and-a-look-into-the-future.md).

---

**Specs:**
Ubuntu 18.0.4 (64 bit)

Answer (score 1):

You can update core-js by running this command:

```
npm install --save core-js@^3
```